# How to print contents of a tkinter.Canvas widget?

Tags: python, printing, tkinter-canvas

How would I print contents of a Python Tkinter.Canvas widget?

I've read that it's possible to print to a postscript printer from this control but examples are hard to come by.

So, any ideas what is needed to print the contents (including images)?

If you've got a cross-platform method all the better!

Comment: There is no cross-platform method, Tk itself does not provide a printing framework. If your Canvas also contains images and/or widgets, the easiest approach is to take a screenshot of the region and then use an external application to do the printing.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it can only be done using the `postscript` method from the Canvas. This generates a postscript file with the canvas contents.

Check the documentation for details about this method.

Comment: From the Manual: `postscript`: Generates a Postscript rendering of the canvas contents. **Images and embedded widgets are not included.**